# Can a VMware guest use ansible to determine it's own name and/or uuid?

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-facts, vcenter

I'm building an ansible playbook designed to run on a vcenter VM.  It's run on startup by ansible-pull.  My goal is to read the tags on the vm using ansible, then make some config changes to the guest system based on those tags.

The difficulty is that I need to read the tags on the guest from inside the guest.  The vmware_guest_facts module will let me do this, but it requires the name or uuid of the guest.

Currently the only way I can see to do that is to use vmware_vm_facts to get the facts of ALL the VMs, then find the VM where ansible_default_ipv4.address matches the ip address, set that as a fact, then use vmware_guest_facts to read the tags from that VM by UUID.  It seems like overkill.

Is there an easy way for a VM to read its own tags I'm overlooking?

Here's what I have to do now:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_files:
    - vars.yaml

  pre_tasks:
    - name:  Read VMware vm facts
      vmware_vm_facts:
        hostname: "{{vc_host}}"
        password: "{{vc_pass}}"
        username: "{{vc_user}}"
        validate_certs: no
        vm_type: vm
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: vmfacts

    - name: scan for ip
      set_fact:
        vm_uuid: "{{ item.uuid }}"
        vm_name: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
      with_items: "{{ vmfacts.virtual_machines }}"
      when:
        - item.ip_address is defined
        - ansible_default_ipv4.address == item.ip_address


    - name:  Read VMware guest facts
      vmware_guest_facts:
        datacenter: ASDC
        hostname: "{{vc_host}}"
        uuid: "{{vm_uuid}}"
        password: "{{vc_pass}}"
        username: "{{vc_user}}"
        tags: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: vmguestfacts


    - name:  set up tags var
      set_fact:
        vm_tags: "{{ vmguestfacts.instance.tags }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vm_tags }}"
```

Comment: Are these Linux guests? You can find the system UUID using `dmidecode`, which should match the VM UUID. Programmatically retrieved with `dmidecode -s system-uuid`. If Windows I'm sure there is something comparable, but I can't help with that sorry.

Comment: They are linux guests.  However the uuid and hw_product_uuid reported by ansible do not match the uuid reported by dmidecode.  

`dmidecode | grep "Serial Number: VMware"`
returns 
`Serial Number: VMware-xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx-xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx`

and the hex string matches the vmware uuid.  

The catch is that dmidecode requires root access, so I'll have to tweak something else to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain `vmware_vm_facts` and raised a PR https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/60220 to get tags for all Virtual Machines using `vmware_vm_facts`. With this feature you will be able to gather VM tags.

After PR is merged, task will look like this -

```
- name: Get Tags from given VM Name
  block:
    - name: Get virtual machine facts
      vmware_vm_facts:
        hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
        username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
        password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
        folder: "/datacenter/vm/folder"
        show_tag: True
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: vm_facts

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.tags }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ vm_facts.virtual_machines | json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?guest_name=='DC0_H0_VM0']"
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can comment on PR or test this PR.

Answer (score 0):

The version I posted above takes 37 seconds to run, because it's requesting info on ALL vms on the vCenter.  I discovered that `dmidecode -s system-serial-number` will give the system serial which matches the uuid of the vm in hex format `Serial Number: VMware-xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx-xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx`

The following runs in about 7 seconds:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_files:
    - vars.yaml

  pre_tasks:
    - name:  get uuid
      shell: |
        sudo /usr/sbin/dmidecode -s system-serial-number
      register: dmiout

    - set_fact:
        singleuuid: "{{ dmiout.stdout | regex_replace('.*VMware-(.*)$', '\\1') | replace(' ','') | replace('-','') }}"

    - set_fact:
        localuuid: "{{singleuuid[0:8]}}-{{singleuuid[8:12]}}-{{singleuuid[12:16]}}-{{singleuuid[16:20]}}-{{singleuuid[20:32]}}"

    - name:  Read VMware guest facts
      vmware_guest_facts:
        datacenter: ASDC
        hostname: "{{vc_host}}"
        uuid: "{{localuuid}}"
        password: "{{vc_pass}}"
        username: "{{vc_user}}"
        tags: yes
        validate_certs: no
      register: vmguestfacts


    - name:  set up tags var
      set_fact:
        vm_tags: "{{ vmguestfacts.instance.tags }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vm_tags }}"
```

The only catch is that dmidecode requires root access to run.  Since this is running as a normal user foouser, I had to add this line to sudoers:

```
foouser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/dmidecode
```

This whole thing is clunkier than I'd like, so in the next iteration I'll probably change the playbook to run as root, so I can remove the sudo needs.

EDIT:
Someone asked what the regex does, so here's a bit of explanation.  We start with

```
sudo /usr/sbin/dmidecode -s system-serial-number
```

which returns

```
VMware-24 25 26 27 76 15 29 9d-0e 56 e5 b3 52 9f 41 a2
```

The first regex_replace replaces **VMware-** with nothing, giving us

```
24 25 26 27 76 15 29 9d-0e 56 e5 b3 52 9f 41 a2
```

The second replace replaces spaces with nothing, giving us

```
242526277615299d-0e56e5b3529f41a2
```

The third replace replaces the dash with nothing, giving us

```
242526277615299d0e56e5b3529f41a2
```

The next line adds dashes at the correct locations to turn that into a valid uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update, I use Ansible fact instead of the `shell` module:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    singleuuid: "{{ ansible_product_serial | regex_replace('.*VMware-(.*)$', '\\1') | replace(' ','') | replace('-','') }}"
```